# Different result when running the same code in PYCharm and Spyder IDEs

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I'm new with Python and TensorFlow as well. I'm currently writing my master thesis and it's all about machine learning in risk assessment.

I have started with the tutorial [Build a linear model with Estimators](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/linear).

I have both PyCharm and Spyder and I'm in my "evaluation phase", trying to figure out which one I like most.

The thing is, I tried to run the same code (copy and paste from the link above) on both the IDEs, and I was astonished when I noticed that while Spyder produced almost the same results shown in the tutorial, PyCharm produced a "Precision" equal to 0.0 and a "recall" equal to 0.0 as well!

Do you have any idea? How is this possible? (***Edit***: see bottom comments)

Here is the code, I've removed the useless lines, but everything is just copy and paste from the link provided.

Thank you in advance for the help!

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import tensorflow as tf

import tensorflow.feature_column as fc

import os
import sys

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output

tf.enable_eager_execution()

import census_dataset
import census_main

census_dataset.download("/tmp/census_data/")

train_file = "/tmp/census_data/adult.data"
test_file = "/tmp/census_data/adult.test"

import pandas

train_df = pandas.read_csv(train_file, header = None, names = census_dataset._CSV_COLUMNS)
test_df = pandas.read_csv(test_file, header = None, names = census_dataset._CSV_COLUMNS)

import functools

train_inpf = functools.partial(census_dataset.input_fn, train_file, num_epochs=2, shuffle=True, batch_size=64)
test_inpf = functools.partial(census_dataset.input_fn, test_file, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False, batch_size=64)

age = fc.numeric_column('age')

classifier = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=[age])
classifier.train(train_inpf)

result = classifier.evaluate(test_inpf)

clear_output()

print(result)
```

The result obtained in the web page of the tutorial were:

```
{precision': 0.1780822, 'label/mean': 0.23622628, 'accuracy_baseline': 0.76377374, 'prediction/mean': 0.23925366, 'auc': 0.6783024, 'loss': 33.404175, 'recall': 0.0033801352, 'average_loss': 0.5231905, 'auc_precision_recall': 0.31137863, 'accuracy': 0.7608869, 'global_step': 1018}
```

The results from my simulation on Spider are:

```
{'accuracy': 0.7570788, 'accuracy_baseline': 0.76377374, 'auc': 0.67830646, 'auc_precision_recall': 0.3113795, 'average_loss': 0.52337015, 'label/mean': 0.23622628, 'loss': 33.415646, 'precision': 0.1572327, 'prediction/mean': 0.25014463, 'recall': 0.00650026, 'global_step': 1018}
```

The results from my simulation on PyCharm are:

```
{'accuracy': 0.76377374, 'accuracy_baseline': 0.76377374, 'auc': 0.678149, 'auc_precision_recall': 0.31129122, 'average_loss': 0.5285897, 'label/mean': 0.23622628, 'loss': 33.7489, 'precision': 0.0, 'prediction/mean': 0.20146999, 'recall': 0.0, 'global_step': 1018}
```

please note that only "precision" and "recall" are far from the exact results, the other data provided by PyCharm are similar to the correct ones.

***Edit***: I've made some tests, previously I was using the python console only, I've noticed that also Spyder gives precision and recall equals to 0.0 if I run the entire code in 2 or 3 console calls (i.e. not running the code line by line, but running groups of 3/4 lines, copying and pasting in a single console line multiple instructions)

I've tried to run the code line by line in PyCharm and it does not provide null recall and precision. now the results are:

```
{'accuracy': 0.75062954, 'accuracy_baseline': 0.76377374, 'auc': 0.67835987, 'auc_precision_recall': 0.31139243, 'average_loss': 0.5241894, 'label/mean': 0.23622628, 'loss': 33.467953, 'precision': 0.17378049, 'prediction/mean': 0.26093897, 'recall': 0.0148205925, 'global_step': 1018}
```

Way better. I was wandering, all these differences were arisen just by running multiple instructions in the console? Is always a good idea to just run line by line when using the console?

Comment: Were you able to find the reason for this? I am facing a similar issue with Logistic Regression. Running the file in Pycharm gives different error than copying the file and running in Python Console.

Comment: Same question as @ReshamWadhwa, did you ever find a reason for this? I'm currently lost as to which numbers I could report as the correct ones. It is so weird.